# While loop with one record in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

if the above query returns only one record, then it is not going through the while loop. while loop is getting executed only when i have multiple rows from the select query. So how can i change this while loop to execute for both scenarios (one record or multiple records) in c#

```
OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();                   
command.CommandText = "select * from test where id = 2";

int rowcount = 0;
while (reader.Read())
{
    rowcount++;
}
if (rowcount == 0)
{
     MessageBox.Show("No reords found");
       return;
}
```

Comment: What is the type of the reader variable?

Comment: the code is incomplete. We don't see where `reader` comes from.

Comment: Normally for a .NET reader such as OracleDbReader, you need to call reader = command.ExecuteReader(); and then call reader.Read() for each row.

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracledatareader.read(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: If reader.Read() returns false, you probably have no result looking your code.

Answer (score 0):

we can't see all of the code so we can't see what is wrong with it but generally some times ppl forget to actually call the reader this way the while loop condition will never happen 
it's also more safe to put your table's name in []

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like:

```
if (reader.Read())
{
    // at least one record available
    do
    {
        // work with reader
    } while (reader.Read()); // true while another records available
}
else
{
    // no records found
}
```

Comment: Downvoter, please read the question of the author. My message corresponds exactly to both scenarios.

Comment: Can you explain why OP's code doesn't work, and how your version of the code is better?

Comment: @sstan - OP's code works. And my too. But no need `rowcount`.

Comment: Thank you! reader.Read returns false for me. I might be posted this one prematurely. I am in process of debugging it now. Thanks again for the response